# How does the cloud save in Skulls of the Shogun work?

Tags: skulls-of-the-shogun

I played Skulls of the Shogun on my Windows 8 device for about 30 minutes, making fair progress in the first level. The campaign was saved both through autosave and through explicit saving.

I then started the game on my Windows Phone 8 device and expected to load a game from the cloud and continue the campaign at last save. No such luck however. The explicit saves doesn't seem the be saved in the cloud at all and the autosaves only seem to hit the cloud when I finish a level in the campaign.

Is this how the cloud saves should work or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I believe that those are the mechanics of the save. If you want a game to be saved on the cloud, you must complete the level.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the phone is that it may say its connected to Xbox Live, but it's not. Go to your Xbox Live app, choose ... at the bottom, then choose Refresh. If that works the cloud saved data should load.